# Insert Obj into List using c# Linq

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, linq

I am trying to insert an object into a list.

```
 childModel childElement= new childModel;

 parentModel myList = db.list.Where(e => e.id.equals(someId)).Include("someNestedList").FirstOrDefault();

 childElement.prop1 = true;
 myList.someNestedList.Insert(index, childElement);
```

So I notice that from here everything works fine in the sense that it will insert the child object into the list at the appropriate index. The issue arises when I try saving this list.

```
 db.Entry(myList).State = EntityState.Modified;
 db.SaveChanges();
```

I notice that it doesn't save the index within the database but rather adds another entry. with the next available id. So what I am saying is that it doesnt rearrange the Primary Key once I insert the value.

Is it better to not use the insert Method and just use db.Entry() = EntityState.Modified for each child element?

Any advice?

Comment: EF uses the id (primary key) to know what row you are updating.  So, this is not nearly as simple as you might think it would be.  Basically you need to update the item at that index with the new values and update all the following ones with the previous and create a new one with the values of the last (assuming your list is ordered by the id and we're talking about an identity).  Though you might want to reconsider your design so you don't need to do this in the first place.

Comment: Yes so that would be my second suggestion where you would have to modify each element again. When you say design are you talking about not using the id/primary key as the value for sorting?

Comment: I mean why do you need to insert a new element in the "middle" by your primary key id?  If there is an order you need to maintain then maybe a separate column could be used for that, but again you'd have to do a lot of updates just to change the order.

Comment: Well I am using my primary key id for sorting rather than creating a new column. I wanted to insert a new element in the middle because its actually a nestedList (clarified by my updated code)

Answer (score 0):

When you use .ToList() you're creating a new instance, therefore when you do SaveChanges, EF doesn't know this new instance, so it will insert a new item in your table.

You can see here a good example: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/update-one-to-many-entities-in-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: I updated my code a bit. So its actually a nested List inside an object. That being said I don't think I'm creating a new instance unless I'm wrong about that. From there I will be inserting a value into the nested list.